# How do I configure vs code not to use the default dotnet path?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I configure vs code not to use the default dotnet path?

I have configured the terminal $env:PATH so I can use .net6 which works great. When I try to run my code from the menu I notice the run command is not using the same path as the terminal. I do not have admin access to the computer so therefore my options are limited.

[old dotnet path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtRTt.png)

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone with non-admin access trying to install more recent versions of dotnet and then use them in vscode

- use dotnet_install.ps1 to install dotnet in your user profile
- create a simple batch file
- set your new dotnet folder as the first item in your path
- launch vscode from the same batch file

Chris